# Help to create the best plugin settings!

Tags: options, rest-api, api, settings-api, wp-api

Can you help me about how to create the best WordPress settings for plugins?

I have a custom setting page and I need to create some field with WordPress API.

Actually I use this solution: https://gist.github.com/DavidWells/4653358  (* it's working fine) but I think it is not enough and optimizes, I just need your the standard guideline and your recommended(in this time — WP v5.4.2).

I appreciate your advice,

Thanks.

Comment: Best for what? Please explain your specific problem better. And welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: I mean plugin settings fields(an options for plugin): https://deliciousbrains.com/create-wordpress-plugin-settings-page/ (not page)

Comment: "Best" is extremely subjective. If your code works, you understand it and can maintain it comfortably, then it's the best for you. The exact same code might be a nightmare for another person.